# Why are my styles not getting applied to elements in nextjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I have added the following classes to elements as follows:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="notes-header">Index Page</h1>
      <Link href="./notes">
        <a className="notes-home">Notes</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Next, I added styling to my element as follows

```
.notes-header {
  font-size: 100px;
}

.notes-home {
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

Lastly, I created a _app.js file and imported the global css file as shown below:

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/globals.css";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

The problem is my styles don't get applied to my selected elements. What I'm I getting wrong?

Comment: Is your`.js` file located in the same folder as your `_app.js`?

Comment: Yes it is in the same folder.

Comment: Where is your `Page` component rendering?

Comment: Did you restart after create _app.js ?

Comment: My Page component is rendering in the index.jsx file which is in the pages folder. _app.js is in the pages folder as well.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. See working codesandbox example with the same exact code: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-bird-1v5wm7.

Comment: Thank you @juliomalves. I am not sure what the issue is.  I have shifted to css modules in the meantime.